# Apache / Tomcat | Connection reset by peer: ajp_ilink_receive() can't receive header

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat

We are getting the below error inconsistently in production and we are not sure what the root cause is:

> [error] (104)Connection reset by peer: ajp_ilink_receive() can't receive header
>   [error] ajp_read_header: ajp_ilink_receive failed
>   [error] (120006)APR does not understand this error code: proxy: read response failed from XXX.XX.XX.XXX:8009 (XXX.XX.XX.XXX)

Our architecture:
F5 Load balancer -> Web servers (httpd mod_proxy ajp load balancer) -> App server (Tomcat with AJP connector)

Note that F5 is used to load balance the apache httpd web servers only (2 in total). Then, we are using apache mod_proxy_ajp to load balance our app servers (5 in total)

Does anyone know what is causing the "connection reset by peer" error on the web server?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. SO is more for programming issues. You might be able to get a quicker and better response on the Unix/Linux SO or Serverfault.com